# Rectangular selection in Highcharts columnrange

Tags: javascript, highcharts, selection

I would like to enable rectangular selection in Highcharts columnrange chart like this one:

[image]

To do so, I would like to get coordiantes of the selected region as well as exact coordinates of the recangles corresponding to each of the columnranges. Then I would simply check if selection overlaps with some columnrange and mark it selected.

I know how to get coordinates of the selection region and how to get low and high values of each of the columnranges. To determine which columnranges are under selection I would also need to find the `x` coordinates of the each of the columnranges, which I don't know how to do. If I look at the `x` attribute of the columnrange I only see the index of the group (e.g. 0 or 1) which only tells me inside which group (e.g. Jan, Feb, ...) the current column range resides.

How do I get the exact x coordinates (something like from 2.75 to 2.95 for last blue column) of the rectangles for columranges to enable finding out which are under the selected region?

Here's the fiddlle: https://jsfiddle.net/nikicc/0mhhma2d/

Comment: not clear _(something like from 2.75 to 2.95 for last blue column)_ what is 2.75 to 2.95 how you are getting it

Comment: I meant 2.75 to 2.95 since last blue columnrange is plotted on x coordinates around 3 (since it is 4th group) but is plotted a bit to the left of the centre of the Apr section. I was trying to project columnrange to the data's coordinate system but @morganfree provided a solution below where you work in the coordiante system of pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shape of the column is stored in `point.shapeArgs` but those values are in pixels - so you need to translate them to the axis values or translate selection events coords to pixels. Then you can check if the column is inside in the selection rect.

```
        var xAxis = e.xAxis[0],
      yAxis = e.yAxis[0];

    var xLeft = xAxis.axis.toPixels(xAxis.min, true),
      xRight = xAxis.axis.toPixels(xAxis.max, true),
      yBottom = yAxis.axis.toPixels(yAxis.min, true),
      yTop = yAxis.axis.toPixels(yAxis.max, true);

    this.series.forEach((series, j) => {
      series.data.forEach((point, i) => {
        var shapeArgs = point.shapeArgs;
        var inside = (
          shapeArgs.x > xLeft &&
          shapeArgs.x + shapeArgs.width < xRight &&
          shapeArgs.y > yTop &&
          shapeArgs.y + shapeArgs.height < yBottom
        );

        point.select(inside, true)
      });
    });
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/f400L2p2/

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Tnx :)